# Launching External Executable in Windows Azure

Tags: asp.net, ffmpeg, azure, remote-desktop, external-process

My current ASP.NET site requires to launch FFMPEG.EXE to convert uploaded videos.  With shared web hosting server, can't be done but via a Virtual Private Server (VPS) or a dedicated server.

I've been reading some info about Windows Azure but haven't found any info regarding: 
1. Be able to launch external executable 
2. Be able to remote desktop into the allocated virtual machines

Please advise, thanks!
Eddie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, you can launch an executable.  (Just Process.Start() it!)  Note that if you use local disk space, you'll need to declare that in your .csdef file and use the RoleEnvironment API to discover the path you should use to write to.

You can't remote desktop into allocated VMs yet.  That's coming later this year.